# Python input restriction and repromoting

Tags: python, list, restrict

I wanted to restrict the user input from 1 - 223 excluding " 3 , 7 , 10 , 12 "
and when the user enter one of these numbers i want to print an error and ask to re-promote the entry from the user .. I have the problem in listing the excluded numbers and in the repromoting code ..

This is where i have stopped

```
for i in range(numRan):
    ranNums.append(int(raw_input( "Range %d Number ? (1-223)\n" % (i+1) )))
    if i in []:
        print "Rang is not allowed!"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "re-promote"? Re-input?

Answer (score 2):

This works- including retaking the input if it is not valid:

```
allowed_nums = set(range(1,224)) - {3,7,10,12}
for i in range(numRan):
    while True:
        inpt = int(raw_input("Range %d Number? (1-223)\n" % (i+1)))
        if inpt in allowed_nums:
            ranNums.append(inpt)
            break
        print "Range is not allowed!"
```

So the way this basically works is that for every iteration, or input we create an infinite loop that only breaks to thus move onto the next input iteration when the input is valid.

Comment: Does not restrict numbers to 1-223

Comment: +1 take it easy man. you are just 14years of age... nice to see you on stack overflow at such lower age... :)

Comment: remember the purpose of `rep` is to provide of correct answer to someone who is searching for the same question. ie moreupvotes means good solution ..... :)

Comment: As an aside, try doing `allowed_nums = set(range(1,224))-{3,7,10,12}` and then testing `if inpt in allowed_nums`. Faster and prettier than the boolean `and`

Comment: @adsmith Yeah I thought about that afterwards. A perfectly valid answer and more concise.

Comment: come to chat man http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50191/settuple. now the code seems nice.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
not_allowed = {3,7,10,12}
for i in range(numRan):
    while True: # to repeat raw_input if the input is not_allowed
        val = int(raw_input( "Range %d Number ? (1-223)\n" % (i+1) )))
        if val in not_allowed or val < 1 or val > 223:
            print "Rang is not allowed!"
        else:
            ranNums.append(val)
            break
```

Comment: This does not fulfil the user's requirement of looping back to the input when it is invalid.

Comment: Amended it to do that

Comment: Thanks , everything good , i tried to add the the restriction for the input more than 223 and less than 1 but didn't gone well could you please advise ?

Comment: IT's faster. O(1) instead of O(n). So upto 4 * faster in this case as it does a hash lookup not a linear search

Comment: then you can use `tuple` instead(ie:`(3,7,10,12)`. it is much faster.

Comment: It's not inefficient. You just said yoruself it's the same solution as you have. I do not understand. Plus creating a list of items to do an in (in range(1,224) if far LESS efficient that an bounds check. You need to spend your time doing constructive things and not criticizing others. There are plenty of sites on the internet for flame wars. Go waste your time there.

Comment: @suhail I did some tests on a large tuple vs a large set, the set was about 80,000 times faster if the size of both is 1,000,000. Is it faster for a tuple if the size is small? I don't see how you can get faster than O(1) but I am unsure how python handles tuples, but I assume it's doing a linear search as with the list.

Comment: is it possible to chat??

Comment: @Suhail Sure. How do I do that?

Comment: Ok, we concluded a set is faster, so long as you are searching it multiple times. A tuple is faster to construct, so use it if you are doing a one time only test.

Comment: Don't know about copying, I'm not seeing any of that here, but I would suggest that you simply avoid telling users to accept your answer. Especially not in that demanding tone, and especially not *repeatedly*. If you want to educate users about accepting answers, describe how it works, link to the help center, etc, and be polite, not terse about it - otherwise it's better to just wait and see if they discover the feature for themselves.

Comment: @BoltClock I am just telling everyone what, after a long discussion and some testing, we discovered regarding the speed of a tuple vs a set.

Answer (score 0):

I usually write a function for inputs that have to re-prompt the user

```
def limited_input(prompt="",include_only=None,not_allowed=None,not_allowed_err="",cast=None,wrongcasterr=""):
    if not_allowed is None:
        not_allowed = set()
    in_ = None
    while in_ is None:
        in_ = raw_input(prompt)
        if cast:
            try: in_ = cast(in_)
            except ValueError:
                print wrongcasterr
                in_ = None
                continue
        if (include_only and in_ not in include_only) or in_ in not_allowed:
            print not_allowed_err
            in_ = None
    return in_
```

Then you can use it as usual:

```
for i in range(numRan):
    ranNums.append(limited_input(prompt="Range %d Number ? (1-223)\n" % (i+1),
                                 include_only = range(1,224),
                                 not_allowed = {3,7,10,12},
                                 not_allowed_err = "You cannot use 3,7,10,12"
                                 cast = int
                                 wrongcasterr = "You must enter an integer"))
```

This solution is highly portable, and I usually include it in some module or another in my python lib. On this system it's in `utils.inpututils` but YMMV

Comment: Does not restrict numbers to range 1-223

Comment: True, but easily fixed.

Comment: @adsmith There is no way this deserves a downvote. Take mine, +1.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier for you to separate the function which asks for the function, and creating a list of numbers layer, like so:

```
restrict = [3,7,10,12]

# This function returns an input number with the right 
# characteristics. 
def strictInput():
    v = int(raw_input('Number?'))
    if v >0 and v<224 and v not in restrict: return v
    print 'Illegal number ..., try again'
    return strictInput()

# Now call this function however many times you need ...
inputNumbers = [strictInput() for i in range(numRan)]
```